# VMware vFabric tc Server won't start

Tags: eclipse, server-error

I just start having trouble running projects in Eclipse Juno on VMware vFabric tc Server. I have have Spring STS 3.1.0 installed. This was running this morning. Now when I try to run my project on the VMware server I will not get the home page to come up. There are no error messages generated. When I click on the button to stop the server and try again a pop-up is display saying 'Server VMware vFabric tc Server v2.5, v2.6, v2.7 at localhost failed to start'. When I click the Details tab the same message is displayed. Something got corrupted but I have no idea what. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Thanks 
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

press `ctrl+alt+del` choose task-manager go to "processes" tab and kill the (VMware vFabric) process that got stuck - then try again.

Comment: Well, that does work thanks, however the result is it kills off Firefox??

Comment: @MikeHT Don't worry about it! first, you can use Eclipse (STS) built-in browser or simply restart FF.

Comment: I usually have Firefox open for a reason...I'm looking at forums/websites for info related to what I"m doing. Anyway at this point I noticed that if I just wait a bit longer (maybe 10-15 seconds) the server now comes up and runs fine without having to kill Firefox. Not sure what is going on but.....thanks

Comment: @MikeHT NP. After you killed the zombie process of `VMware vFabric`, STS managed to bring it back up. I'm not sure why FF went down though, maybe you killed another process as well (without noticing) which is required by FF.

Comment: I don't think I specifically killed Firefox, at least not the second and third times I tried it as I was careful not to kill Firefox, but like I said I don't really understand what happened at this point. It's running fine now and that's the important thing. Thanks again.